# How to use specific maven and jdk on Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I have corporate Jenkins where I don't have access to Manage Jenkins option. I want to make a build of my java app using maven.
When I try to run mvn clean install:

```
dir("test/test2/project") {
sh "mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true"
}
```

I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (/var/jenkins/workspace/test/test2/project). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory.
```

I was trying to add mvn -f /var/jenkins/workspace/test/test2/project/pom.xml (I have pom file in the folder) but it did not work.
I also tried

```
withEnv(["PATH+MAVEN=${tool 'maven-3.5.0'}/bin:${env.JAVA_HOME}/bin"]) {
sh "mvn --batch-mode -V -U -e clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true"
```

which also did not work.

I would like to point to maven and java which are installed on the agent but can't seem to sucseed.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like below?

```
dir("test/test2/project") {
    sh "mvn clean install"
}
```

Comment: I was using that in my pipeline and the output I have added before is what I get. I will correct the question with hat part of the pipeline.